# Blurry text on Chrome when using CSS -webkit-transform

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transforms

I'm using

```
-webkit-transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
```

to skew a div, and then

```
-webkit-transform: skew(15deg, 0deg);
```

to *deskew* the text-containing child. The skewing looks ugly and pixlated in google chrome, so I use

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to make it look OK. Now the container is skewed very nice and the inside text is "unskewed" but the text itself is blurry and ugly! (problem only exists only in chrome who uses -webkit)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EF9pd/1/)

Any ideas how to make the text clear again?

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainBodyItemBox">
    <div class="mainBodyItemImage">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/2012_Olympic_Football_-_Men's_tournament_-_Honduras_Vs_Morocco.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="mainBodyItemDecorator"></div>
    <div class="mainBodyItemText">PEC Zwolle v FC Groningen Tickets
        <br> <span class="mainBodyItemType">Football</span>
 <span class="mainBodyItemTime"><strong>04 Apr 2014</strong> | 21:00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainBodyItemBox {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 365px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.mainBodyItemImage {
    height: 100%;
    width: 125px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.mainBodyItemDecorator {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    background: rgb(30, 143, 30);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e8f1e', endColorstr='#47d115', GradientType=0);
}
.mainBodyItemText {
    color: #323d50;
    font-size: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 125px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
}
.mainBodyItemType {
    color: #9aa7af;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.mainBodyItemTime {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fd2XL/ looks ok to me on Chrome33. Which version of Chrome are you using? Also, can you add more code to the question that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: See here: http://jsfiddle.net/fd2XL/1/ after adding -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; the blurriness appears!

Comment: OK, I guess I can't see what you are skewing. In my small demo I didn't need `backface-visibility` on the parent as there was no apparent blurriness. You can add `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden` to the text as well to remove the pixelation

Comment: Here's the original pixlated skew: http://jsfiddle.net/EF9pd/ here it is after `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`: http://jsfiddle.net/EF9pd/1/ :(

Comment: Hey, any new on this?

Comment: I started playing around with a solution but the text was always blurry. The only thought I had was to just skew the image and end bar, leaving the text alone, which would work. My only issue with that was getting the widths correct. I will see if I can write a demo later.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, really got tired from it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure this will be a viable solution for fixing blurry text but I have created something that seems to avoid the  problem.

The trick I use is to encapsulate all elements that require the `transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg)` in a container and absolutely position the container behind the text. That way, the text is not subject to any *transformation* and therefore does not need to be *deskewed*. I did try separating the text in a different way but the mere proximity to a transformed element was still resulting in blurry text.

I have created 2 demos, [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/N82GL/) retains your original HTML and [**this one**](http://jsfiddle.net/N82GL/1/) using something a bit cleaner and more semantic. It is the latter that I have also included the code for below.

**HTML**

```
<article>
    <section>
        <h1>PEC Zwolle v FC Groningen Tickets</h1>
        <p>Football</p>
        <time><strong>04 Apr 2014</strong> | 21:00</time>
    </section>
    <aside>
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/2012_Olympic_Football_-_Men's_tournament_-_Honduras_Vs_Morocco.jpg" /><b></b>
    </aside>
</article>
```

**CSS**

```
article, aside {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 365px;
}

article {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
aside {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
    transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 125px;
}
aside b {
    right:0;
    top:0;
    position:absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10px;
    background: rgb(30, 143, 30);
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64, PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJod…EiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30, 143, 30, 1) 0%, rgba(71, 209, 21, 1) 100%);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#1e8f1e', endColorstr='#47d115', GradientType=0);
}
section {
    color: #323d50;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left:140px;
}
section h1 {
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:5px 0 0;
}
section p {
    color: #9aa7af;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: 5px 0;
}
time {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my simple version based on yours:

WITH AUTO WIDTH !  :)

https://jsfiddle.net/CastelMTL/x2Lhhdmj/1/

HTML:

```
  <article>
    <section>
        <p>Football</p>
    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
</article>
<article>
    <section>
        <p>Football Player</p>
    </section>
    <aside>
    </aside>
</article>
```

CSS:
        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900,900italic);

```
article, aside {
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    width:auto;
}

article {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
aside {
width:100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
border-width: 4px;
border-color: red;
background-color: #f5f5f5;
border: 3px solid #04B552;
border-radius: 3px;
/* border-bottom: 1px solid #c9c9c9; */
transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
-webkit-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
-moz-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
-o-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
-ms-transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

section {
    color: #323d50;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left:0px;
    display: block;
}
section p {
    font-family:'lato';
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:15px;
    font-weight:normal;
    margin:10px 15px;
}

time {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```