# Animation of opacity causes blurry text on other divs

Tags: css, google-chrome, animation

In chrome my text appears blurry, I've tracked the issue down to my `animation` in my css file but I have no idea why it is causing this.

(make sure you open the image otherwise you don't see a lot of difference)

**Enabled animation (blurry)**
[image]

**Disabling the animation (crisp)**
[image]

I have tried a lot of options that I found on stack overflow but none solve my issue...

- [Chrome Font appears Blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385126/chrome-font-appears-blurry)
- [CSS transition effect makes image blurry / moves image 1px, in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464055/css-transition-effect-makes-image-blurry-moves-image-1px-in-chrome)
- [WebKit: Blurry text with css scale + translate3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024061/webkit-blurry-text-with-css-scale-translate3d)
- [Blurry text on Chrome when using CSS -webkit-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654978/blurry-text-on-chrome-when-using-css-webkit-transform)
- [Chrome animation makes text blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40012420/chrome-animation-makes-text-blurry)

**Animation itself**

```
@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
}

animation: blink 2s infinite;
```

**Example of animation**
[image]

Comment: What animation styles are you using? Can you share them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just how chrome is. Animations and transitions are blurry.

Comment: @Terry See updated question

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb See updated question

Comment: I saw it, my comment still applies.

Comment: But it blurs all other text, the blurred text has nothing to do with the animation... The animation is on the arrows not on the title or the other text :(

Comment: Can you post either your full code, or at least a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb I am unable to recreate this in a jsfiddle -_- (https://jsfiddle.net/jao3kpef/)

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb it seems to be an issue with my resolution in chrome? If I make the window smaller it works out fine but on full screen size it seems blurry. My screen size is `2560 x 1440`

Comment: If you can't reproduce your issue, how can you expect us to help you with troubleshooting?

Comment: @Terry I really have no idea... How can I recreate a problem existing in a fairly large project that only occurs when I have chrome at full size when my animation is activated?

Comment: Use the 50/50 rule. Take half of the code out. Does it go away? If yes: the issue probably lies in the half that was taken out. No? The issue lies in the half that remain. Rinse and repeat. Asking a question here means that you invest in some effort in creating a **minimal, concrete and verifiable** example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've solved the issue and it was because my wrapper component had `position: relative;` which somehow caused the rest to be blurry when the `transform` was applied.

Look for a parent that has the `position:relative;`

Comment: nice!! tks bro!